# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Object'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutterflow

I'm getting the below error, I'm creating a custom action in flutter flow.

Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Object' because 'String?' is nullable and 'Object' isn't.

*code*

```
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

// Set your action name, define your arguments and return parameter,
// and then add the boilerplate code using the button on the right!

import 'package:image_downloader_web/image_downloader_web.dart';

final WebImageDownloader _webImageDownloader = WebImageDownloader();

Future imagedownloaderweb(String url) async {
  // Add your function code here!
  await _webImageDownloader.downloadImageFromWeb(url);
}
```

[image: flutter-flow-custom-widget]

[image: image_downloader_web]

Answer (score 0):

All methods on `WebImageDownloader` are static, you should not instantiate an instance of this class via `WebImageDownloader()`.

Instead you can directly call

```dart
WebImageDownloader.downloadImageFromWeb(url);
```

More info in the source code [here](https://github.com/hrvojecukman/image_downloader_web/blob/main/lib/src/web_image_downloader.dart) or documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader_web)

Comment: Instance member 'downloadImageFromWeb' can't be accessed using static access.

Comment: Pardon, I did not notice you were using version 1.0.2 of `image_downloader_web`. If possible for you, you should probably update to the latest version 2.0.2

Comment: Latest Version doesn't works across all platforms. This one does.